# Is there a way to copy a function between MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, function

I'm creating a dev copy of a live databases with some modifications for testing. Is there a way to copy a MySQL user defined FUNCTION between databases? Or do I need to recreate it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use mysqldump with `--routines` options to export them from your source db:

```
mysqldump <other mysqldump options> --routines > your_output_file.sql
```

And to import them in the destination db, use

```
mysql <database> < your_output_file.sql
```

You can see the mysqldump reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)