# PostgreSQL: Copy/import a user defined function from one database to another database

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964399/is-there-a-way-to-copy-a-function-between-mysql-databases), but for PostgreSQL. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.12 (x64) on my Windows 10 (x64) machine. I have a function (written in `plpgsql`) `my_func()` in database `my_db`. Is it possible to import/copy this function to another database in postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In psql the `\ef` command will open the function in an editor you can then save it to a file...  unfortunately the UI of the  windows version of `psql` was pretty cruddy last time I checked.

a `pg_dump` of the database with `--schema-only` will also include all function definitions.  you can then open it in an editor and copy the functions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [pg_get_functiondef](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) to get function definition as follows:

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(oid) AS definition FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'my_func';
```