# Postgres 11 - how to copy functions from one schema to another

Tags: postgresql

Need to copy some functions from one schema to another.    Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK there is no shortcut or direct command for it. refer this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646705/postgresql-copy-import-a-user-defined-function-from-one-database-to-another-dat) for similar answer

Comment: Can you change the scope of a function so that it is accessible from every schema within a database?   So rather than copy the functions,  I can just grant access to them.

Comment: @sparcusa: why copy? Why not simply use it with a fully qualified name? e.g. `select the_schema.the_function()`? Or add the function's schema to the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(oid)
FROM pg_proc
WHERE pronamespace = 'mxschema'::regnamespace;
```

If you have custom defined aggregate functions, you would have to exclude them.